# How to display a time in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
ID TimeColumn

001 13.00
002 03.30
003 14.00
004 23.00
005 08.30
...
```

---

Table1 Format

```
TimeColumn Format: HH:MM
TimeColumn Datatype is nvarchar
TimeColumn will display the time One Hour or HalfHour
TimeColumn will not display 08.20, 08.56. It will display the time like 08.00, 08.30.
```

I want to display a time like 13 instead of 13.00, 3.5 instead of 03.30.

Expected Output

```
ID   TimeColumn  Value

001  13.00       13
002  03.30       3.5
003  14.00       14
004  23.00       23
005  18.30       18.5
...
```

How to make a query for the above condition?

Comment: There is a discrepancy in `Format: HH:MM` and `sample value: 13.00`. Is it colon or period?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid first digit in the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038480/how-to-avoid-first-digit-in-the-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your facts, there are only 2 cases for the last 3 digits, either

- **.30**; or
- **.00**

So we just replace them

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TimeColumn,
    Value = replace(replace(TimeColumn, '.30', '.5'), '.00', '')
From Table1
```

#### EDIT

To drop the leading 0, you can use this instead (the Value column is numeric)

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TimeColumn,
    Value = round(convert(float,TimeColumn)*2,0)/2
From Table1
```

Or if you need it to be varchar

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TimeColumn,
    Value = right(round(convert(float,TimeColumn)*2,0)/2,5)
From Table1
```

Comment: Your Query is working, but when the timecolumn value like this means 03.30, your query is displaying like this 03.5, but i want to display like this 3.5 only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(hour,TimeColumn) + 
  1 / DATEPART(minute,TimeColumn) * 60 
  AS Value
FROM Table1
```

This is where TimeColumn is DateTime. For Column Type NVarChar use a String function to split hours and minutes.

Comment: It has been **stated** that the column is NVarchar, so not sure about this answer being relevant

Comment: @Richard: just realized beeing not strict with requested column type after posting my answer. Basic idea is to split hours and minutes, convert to int and calculate 'h+1/m*60'

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is how SQL Server stores datetime, you then format it with your flavor of programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
select SUBSTRING('20.30', 1, 2) + (case when SUBSTRING('20.30', 4, 2) = '30' then '.5' else '' end)
```

just replace '20.30' with your column name and add from clause

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @table table (ID nvarchar(10),timevalue nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table values('001','13.00')
INSERT INTO @table values('002','03.30')
INSERT INTO @table values('003','14.00')
INSERT INTO @table values('004','23.00')
INSERT INTO @table values('005','08.30')

select (CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('.3',timevalue)>0) then convert(varchar(2),timevalue,2) 
        else convert(varchar(2),timevalue,2) + '.5'
end)
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With TestInputs As
    (
    Select '001' As Id, Cast('13.00' As nvarchar(10)) As TimeColumn
    Union All Select '002','03.30'
    Union All Select '003','14.00'
    Union All Select '004','23.00'
    Union All Select '005','08.30'
    Union All Select '006','08.26'
    Union All Select '007','08.46'
    Union All Select '008','08.56'
    )
    , HoursMinutes As
    (
    Select Id, TimeColumn
        , Cast( Substring(TimeColumn
                    , 1
                    , CharIndex('.', TimeColumn) - 1 ) As int ) As [Hours]
        , Cast( Substring(TimeColumn
                    , CharIndex('.', TimeColumn) + 1
                    , Len(TimeColumn) ) As int ) As [Minutes]
    From TestInputs
    )
Select Id, TimeColumn
    , [Hours] + Case 
                When [Minutes] < 30 Then 0.0
                When [Minutes] < 60 Then 0.5
                Else 1
                End As Value
From HoursMinutes
```